# How to insert multiple values to an access database from an edit box at once using delphi 7

Tags: ms-access-2007, delphi-7, delphi-2010

I have an access database table named `SalesTable` with the following field names: `item name`, `buying price`, `selling price`, `profit`. I am using an Adoquery and datasource to connect to the access database.  When I want to enter records to `SalesTable`, I use the following code:

```
procedure TSalesForm.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Adoquery1.Open;
  Adoquery1.Insert;
  Adoquery1.FieldValues['Item name'] := edit1.Text;
  Adoquery1.FieldValues['buying price'] := Edit2.Text;
  Adoquery1.FieldValues['selling price'] := Edit4.Text;
  Adoquery1.FieldValues['profit'] := edit3.Text;
  Adoquery1.post;
end;
```

This code inserts records to the `SalesTable` once then I have to repeat the procedure again to enter another record.
However, if I want to insert multiple records at once using the the above code, is there a way I can achieve this instead of using an editbox since it always allows one record at a time? Can this be done using a memo? I can't find a specific search for the solution.

Comment: why not use a DBGrid for this then. I believe that for access database you dont even need to write any code then to save all new and updated data to your database

Comment: @GuidoG thats okay also.  Do you have a code for implementing this using a DBgrid?

Comment: You probably dont even need any code, just drop a DBGrid on your form, and a DataSource component. Set the Datasource of the DBGrid to this DataSource, and set the DataSet of the Datasource to your adoquery and set the adoquery active. Thats it

Comment: @GuidoG I think I did not explain the question well. Suppose I want to insert item name: sugar, bread, rice; buying price: 100, 50, 80; Selling price: 120, 60, 95; profit: 20, 10, 15; respectively. If I were to use the above code I would enter these values to their respective edit box i.e item name _bread_ in  `edit1.Text`, _buying price_ `edit2.Text` _selling price_ `edit4.Text`, _profit_ `edit3.Text`. Then click `BitBtn1`to save the record. I want to save all these records at once with the `BitBtn1` click instead of a single entry every time. How do I achieve these?

Comment: I already know how to connect to the database as you have indicated here "You probably dont even need any code, just drop a DBGrid on your form, and a DataSource component. Set the Datasource of the DBGrid to this DataSource, and set the DataSet of the Datasource to your adoquery and set the adoquery active. Thats it "

Comment: you should edit your question and explain this there so it is more clear for everyone.

Comment: A memo is a ridiculous user interface for entering data for a database. What if instead of *100, 50, 80*, the user types *dog, horse, fruit*? You have no way to do validation. Use data aware controls, create a form, and use that form for entering each row into the database, or use a TDBGrid as suggested and let the user enter content into each field in each row of the database as needed. If you want to enter multiple rows (and you're only dealing with a few), look into TDBCtrlGrid. If I tried to use a memo, either my users would shoot me or I'd shoot myself for the mess I made and had to clean

Comment: Also, using ADOQuery to INSERT, then set individual field values, and then post is ludicrous. Queries are for executing SQL. If you want to use the database as a table, use ADOTable instead. Connect it to your database table, then double-click it to open the Fields editor. Right-click and choose *Add All Fields*. Leave that dialog open, create a new form, and then drag a field from the Fields Editor over and drop it on the form. You now have a label and edit control for entering a value into the field. Rinse and repeat until you have a form. Add a *Save* and *Cancel* button. Voila!

Answer (score 1):

So you want a form where you can edit/insert/delete more than one record on your table, and then save all changes to your database with a click on a button with minimum code ?

You could use a classic setup with a ClientDataSet like this :

Drop on your form the following components:

```
ADOConnection1
ADOQuery1
DataSetProvider1
ClientDataSet1
DataSource1
DBGrid1
Button1
```

now setup the properties like this :

```
ADOConnection1   : just as before
ADOQuery1        : just as before
DataSetProvider1 : property DataSet := ADOQuery1;
ClientDataSet1   : property ProviderName := DataSetProvider1;
                   property Active := true;
DataSource1      : property DataSet := ClientDataSet1;
DBGrid1          : property DataSource := DataSource1;
....
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientDataSet1.ApplyUpdates(0);
end;
```

Now your users can edit more than one record in the grid,
they can insert more than one record in the grid, 
they can delete more than one reocrd in the grid,
and the Button1Click will take care off all updating to the database for you

You can also write `ClientDatSet1.CancelUpdates;` if you want to cancel all changes.

Also make sure that you put `MidasLib`in your uses, like this :

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, unit2, DB, ADODB, StdCtrls, Grids, DBGrids, Provider, DBClient,
  MidasLib; // this one is important whan you use ClientDataSets !!
```

Try this and see if it fits your needs